# Mobile application testing (devices Vs emulators)

Tags: android, ios, testing, mobile

What are the typical errors that are found/ or needs to be tested on actual devices as opposed to emulators while testing mobile applications/games

Comment: it would be nice if you ask question which is more specific...;)

Answer (score 3):

I imagine there's various things that could go wrong, especially with layouts. Besides using multiple emulators with different screen sizes, that's something you'll have to find out in beta testing, when you actually distribute your app to a limited set of users and see what kind of feedback you get. In general, there you shouldn't run into too many problems in this area, as long as you design your layouts to be adaptable to many screen sizes. This sort of thing is hard to anticipate, especially as generally as you've defined your situation.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question there is lot of boundation with emulators to test a app.
Like we can't check functioning of camera, GPS,vibration and many more physical functioning of a android phone.

Comment: Hi, if you get your answer do not forget to accept answer. You have to just click on right symbol under the answer.